# General question on the analysis design

Tags: regression, logistic

I have the following problem.

Three hospitals of similar structure have the very different mortality rate on one certain disease. I would like to analyse the data, whether the location as a factor has an influence on the mortality after adjusting for age, gender, urgencies etc.

My plan is to try logistic regression for this. If a location would show a significant OR, this would mean that the parameters that we cannot measure now (say, the real qualification of the staff) should be investigated further.

Does it make sense?

I have some experience with R including several Coursera courses. I have no formal computer science qualification however and I hesitate to just use the "gun" I have on my computer without some advice.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that could make sense - if I understand what you'd want to do, you'd have an indicator for whether or not the person passed away, and that would be the target of your model. If the hospitals are of similar structure (similar services, resources, etc.) then you could just include a dummy indicator in the regression for each hospital. If the coefficient on that indicator ends up being significant, it would mean that there is something about that hospital that you're not capturing in your model that may be contributing to the deaths.

As an additional note, if you wanted to model across many dissimilar hospitals, for which you would then be including information about each hospital in the regression, you'd want to investigate using a multilevel (aka hierarchical) model.